# How do I get a sharp corner in the curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have created a road from a curve using *Geometry Nodes*, but at the corner I want to have a pointed edge. Why is the curve rounded?

[image]

As in the picture above, the red line in **L** shape shows the sharp pointed corner. Is there any possibility or suggestion. Thanks! I am using Blender version 3.2.2.

[image]

Comment: this is best what I can do https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTZWs.png I cant get upper corner to be at 90 degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the spline type to "Poly", adjust the corner vertex with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and you get:

[image]

Comment: it work perfect. Thanks